# Disable scrolling when interactivePopGestureRecognizer transition is taking place

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, interactivepopgesture

I have implemented the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`. It transitions to the previous page. But the problem is that when the transition takes place, if there is a `UIScrollView` in the current view controller, it starts scrolling. Is there some way to prevent it?

I have added the gesture in my RootViewcontroller:

```
   self.appNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    self.appNavController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    self.appNavController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
    [self.appNavController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

I call this in:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    APP_DELEGATE.rootViewController.appNavController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    APP_DELEGATE.rootViewController.appNavController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the view controller which is being swiped i added the following:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

It worked like a charm.